# Automate insert/run macro for ETL process

Tags: excel, vba, etl

I'm trying to automate an ETL process in which a flat file (.xlsx) is placed into a folder and then a macro I built performs all the necessary transformations to the file.  Right now I have to open the original .xlsx file then manually insert/run the macro (the macro saves and closes the file automatically).  From here I have a program that automatically loads the transformed file into my db.

I was wondering what I could do to automate the inserting and running the macro step?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your workbook as an `xlsm` or `xlsb` file, as `xlsx` workbooks can't contain any vba code.  After that, you can run your macro, either manually, or from a worksheet button.